# UITable из NSArray и огткрыть Detail

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, uitableview

Подскажите, бьюсь уже неделю, как при нажатии на cell сделать так что бы открывалось detailview.

```
NSArray *MyArray = @[@"привет мир1",@"привет мир2",@"привет мир3"];
```

Я открываю storyboard, добавляю новую view, создаю связь при помощи push (deprecated) вписываю id в storyboard segue, а вот что дальше? Ни как не могу найти код для новичков по созданию такой связки.

**PS** На всякий случай выкладываю свой код полностью

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier;
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    _startLocation = newLocation;
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{/* Не удалось получить информацию о местоположении пользователя. */
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.myLocationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        CLLocation *startLocation = self.myLocationManager.location;
        CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.050043 longitude:30.345783];
        CLLocation *location3 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.040000 longitude:30.323994];
        CLLocation *location4 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.037389 longitude:30.322094];
        float betweenDistance=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location2];
        float betweenDistance3=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location3];
        float betweenDistance4=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location4];
        NSArray *stringsArray2 = @[
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance/1000],
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance3/1000],
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", betweenDistance4/1000]
                                   ];
        NSString * combinedStuff = [stringsArray2 componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyBdzbOnbi6GaoqUUJOC6f9XR3k5e5V77b0"];
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.93 longitude:30.35 zoom:9];
        mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
        mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
        mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
        //mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
        //mapView_.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
        //mapView_.center = self.view.center;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:mapView_];
        UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 210)];
        self.data = @[
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance/1000],
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance3/1000],

                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", betweenDistance4/1000]
                      ];
    cellIdentifier = @"rowCell";
    [self.myTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    } else {
        /* Геолокационные службы не активизированы.
         Попробуйте исправить ситуацию: например предложите пользователю
         включить геолокационные службы. */
        NSLog(@"Location services are not enabled");
    }
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.data count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My title" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 210)]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close window" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**
В методе `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` необходимо по имени вызвать переход, вот так:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
```

где segueName - имя вашего перехода.

Так же необходимо в контроллере реализовать метод `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`.

Этот метод вызывается для всех переходов. В нем можно понять для какого перехода был вызван метод сравнив имя перехода и можно настроить detailview - `segue.destinationViewController`:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"]) {
        // Код по настройки segue.destinationViewController
    }
}
```

**Вариант 2**
Вы наверно в InterfaceBuilder сделали переход от контроллера, но можно сделать переход от ячейки на нажатие. Тогда не надо будет при нажатии на ячейку, из кода вызывать переход. Для этого надо в InterfaceBuilder потянуть связь от прототипа ячейки на нужный контроллер и в списке "selection segue" выбрать нужный переход.

Comment: При первом варианте вылетает ошибка Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'segueName'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: Вы не можете сделать переход,ваш контроллер должен быть в навигационном контроллере - UINavigationController. Этот контроллер отвечает за переход от одного контроллера к другому - push.

Comment: Сделайте в storyboard UINavigationController и установите у нег своиство "is initial view controller", тогда он будет загружать как основной контроллер приложения. У него в triggered segue есть "root view controller" свяжите его контроллером списка. Тогда контроллер списка сразу будет загружаться в навигационном контроллере, и можно делать переходы push.

Comment: но я не могу установить is initial view controller так как у меня ещё есть 2 других  UINavigationController и у меня основной контроллер совсем другой

Comment: Чтобы делать push segue вам нужно, чтобы ваш контроллер списка был в  навигационном контроллере. Этот контроллер списка как открывается?